# How to clean up windows in Chromium

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

I've been experimenting with Xubuntu and I noticed something a little strange when using Chromium. Due to Chromium's unique "tab" feature, you essentially have a duplicate title bar that uses extra space. Combine that with the uppermost panel and you essentially have three bars that say the same thing. How can I clean this up and eliminate some of the redundancy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the "Use system title bars and borders" option:
[image]

This will eliminate the title bar, and merge the window control buttons (Close, Minimize, etc.) with the tab bar.